# Possible to play AoE2 without a CD drive?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-the-age-of-kings, windows-8.1

This [earlier StackExchange question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/128054/is-there-any-way-to-play-aoe2-without-a-cd-legally) asked a similar question, but no-one appeared to know how to effect this without downloading new software. I'm primarily interested in a registry or binary hack for use with my legal copy.

My copy of Age of Empires II (Microsoft, 1999) is perfectly legal, bought about 15 years ago. Recently I installed and ran the game on my new laptop running Windows 8.1 and the game still works great!

Like most recent laptop models, there is no in-built CD ROM. You need to plug in an external USB DVD player to install software (from CD or DVD), but generally the CD ROM is not available because it is a hassle to attach to the laptop.

Whenever I try and run AoE2 without the CD, I get the error:

`Please insert the correct CD-ROM, select OK and restart application`

Comment: Is borrowing a removable CD drive to mount the ISO an option?

Comment: The other question is specifically referenced. While related, none of the answers given there are what I'm looking for. If it is not possible, that's a perfectly legitimate response...

Comment: @Studoku: I have a removable CD drive which I used to install the game. Its bulky and awkward to use, though, so tends to sit in a draw. How do I go about converting the CD into an ISO?

Comment: The only reason you seem to consider the other not-a-duplicate is that the answers do not help you. Given that we are addressing the question, not the answers, anything regarding the answer is a moot point; Its still the question your asking, the suggested solutions just don't help. You could try earning a bit more rep and posting a bounty on the old question, specifically requesting a new answer, or you could alter your question so it isn't just a matter of "the other question is related, but the answer is not helpful".

Comment: I would also consider wether your specific question is asking "can I get this game to play without using the CD", or rather "Is there an easy way to use my CD-based software on my computer without a CD drive?". The later might get you some response on SuperUser, and for all extensive purposes, games are considered software, so the responses could very much be helpful.

Comment: @Timelord64: The other question has an answer which is NOT what I'm looking for...but that answer was accepted! That question is not mine to edit nor is the answer what I'm looking for...what to do? I need to ask a similar question and specifically state I am looking for an answer not given in the other question. Your suggestion to try on SuperUser is reasonable.

Comment: If its the same question we still have to mark it as a dupe. The only other option if you just seek an alternate answer is to put a bounty on the original question. You should still be able to place a bounty on an answered question in request of an alternate solution

Comment: OK, understood. I've asked a more general question on SuperUser and will try a bounty on the original question. Thanks!